# программно закруглить углы в MaterialButton

Tags: android, kotlin

в XML работает

```
app:cornerRadius="50dp"
```

программно нет

```
material_button1.cornerRadius = 50
```

Кто сталкивался с таким вопросом, подскажите. Спасибо

Comment: Вы всегда программно таким образом устанавливаете значения? Так и не должно работать. Для этого есть специальные методы (сеттеры).

Comment: @Эникейщик это норма, в котлине методы с приставкой set и get из джавы преобразуются в ствойства. По поводу вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071755/android-how-to-set-corner-radius-programmatically, только там устаревший метод, вместо него просто используйте  `view.background = shape`